# Why am I getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

Tags: java, arrays, exception, bounds, out

Here is my main class,  I cannot figure out why I am getting an array out of bounds error. I know what the why it is going off. any help would be appreciated. it is just giving me that error and I cannot figure out why it is doing that this is the text file also if you would like to know

Make:  Buick
Modle: Regal
Doors: 4

Make:  Hyundai
Modle: Veloster 
Doors: 3

Make:  SmartCar 
Modle: Hard Top 
Doors: 2

Make:  Toyota
Modle: Tacoma
Doors: 2

Make:  Chevy
Modle: Impala
Doors: 4

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cars;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Alex Masse
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cars myCar = new Cars("Buick\t", "Regal\t", 4);
        Cars impala = new Cars("Chevy\t", "Impala\t", 4);
        Cars joesCar = new Cars("Hyundai\t", "Veloster\t", 3);
        SmartCars TheHalwking = new SmartCars("SmartCar\t", "Hard Top\t", 2);
        Truck dadsTruck = new Truck("Toyota\t","Tacoma\t", 2);
        Motorcycle yama = new Motorcycle("Yamaha\t", "Vstar",650,78);
        SportBike z1 = new SportBike("Suzuki\t", "Hybusa\t",1400, 110);//constructors
        CafeRacer suz = new CafeRacer("Suzuki\t","Sérgio Teixeira's\t",750, 80);
        DirtBike kawa=new DirtBike("Kawasaki\t", "KDX50\t",250, 46);

        int opt=0;

        System.out.println("1 --- view list via System print stream\n2 --- Write list to a text file\n3 --- Read list from text file");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select: ");
        opt=sc.nextInt();

        if (opt==1)
        {


        int x=5;
           while (x<5)//dows this 5 times
           {
              z1.speed();//adds 18 so z1 speed
           }
        suz.setHight(1.7);
        suz.setLenght(4.7);
        yama.speed();//adds 10 so yama speed
        myCar.setSpeed(65);
        joesCar.setSpeed(65);
        TheHalwking.setSpeed(20);
        myCar.accelerate();
        TheHalwking.setIntel(80);
        dadsTruck.setBedSize("Small");
        dadsTruck.setSpeed(30);
        dadsTruck.setSpeed(68);
        dadsTruck.accelerate();
        z1.setMaxSpeed(280);
        z1.setZero260(2.78);
        kawa.setHight(2.7);
        kawa.setLenght(5.9);
        kawa.speed();
        System.out.println(myCar.toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(joesCar.toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(TheHalwking.toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(dadsTruck.toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(yama.toString());
        yama.slow();//displays persuit msg
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(z1.toString());
        z1.slow();
        System.out.println(suz.toString());
        System.out.println(kawa.toString());
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(impala.toString());
    }
        if (opt==23421)//DONT USE THIS YET!!!
        {
            PrintWriter out=null;
             try {
                System.out.println("Writing Vehicals to file......");
                out = new PrintWriter(
                        new BufferedWriter(
                                new FileWriter("Veh.txt")));
                    out.println(myCar);
                    out.println(joesCar);
                    out.println(TheHalwking);
                    out.println(dadsTruck);
                    out.println(impala);
                    out.flush();
                    System.out.println("Wrote to file, file has been flushed");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }  
             out.close();
             System.out.println("File has been closed");

            }


        if (opt==3)
        {
            try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("veh.txt"));
            String line = null;
            String rl = in.readLine();
            while (rl!=null)
            {

                String [] c=rl.split("\t");
                String Make=c[0];
                String Model=c[1];
                int Doors=9;//Integer.parseInt(c[2]);

                Cars p = new Cars(Make, Model, Doors);

                System.out.println(p);
                rl=in.readLine();


            }
    }

            catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a line in your file `"veh.txt"` with has no *tab* character. This might happen because you're not writing any delimiter in your `if (opt==23421)` branch.

Comment: Are you sure you used tabs instead of soft tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line

```
String Model=c[1];  // no index 1 in array
```

is giving error because your array dont have index `1`
so if you read first line of file it would be like

```
String rl="Make: Buick";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rl.split("\t")));
```

which gives `[Make: Buick]` ie no index `1` you should check the logic